# как преобразовать словарь в датафрейм

Tags: python, pandas, dict

Подскажите, как можно напечатать некоторые ключи этого словаря в датафрейм?  
В первую очередь интересует как совместить ключи `data` и `arg` в одном датафрейме без фигурных скобок?

```
import pandas as pd


res = {
    "action": "snapshot",
    "arg": {
        "instType": "SPOT",
        "channel": "trade",
        "instId": "BTCUSDT"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "ts": "1695709835822",
            "price": "26293.4",
            "size": "0.0013",
            "side": "buy",
            "tradeId": "1000000000"
        }
    ],
    "ts": 1695711090682
}
df = pd.json_normalize(res,'data','arg')
df
```

Результат должен выглядеть так:

```
ts                  price   size    side tradeId       arg.instId
0   1695709835822   26293.4 0.0013  buy 1000000000     BTCUSDT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае можно сделать так

```
df = pd.DataFrame(res["data"][0] | res['arg'], index=[0]).drop(columns=['instType', 'channel']).rename(columns={'instId':'arg.instId'})
```

```
              ts    price    size side     tradeId arg.instId
0  1695709835822  26293.4  0.0013  buy  1000000000    BTCUSDT
```

**Или так:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(res["data"][0] | {'arg.instId': res['arg']["instId"]}, index=[0])
```

**Еще вариант:**

```
df = pd.json_normalize(res, 'data', 'arg').rename(columns={'arg':'arg.instId'})
df['arg.instId'] = df['arg.instId'].str['instId']
```

Comment: Алексей Р, спасибо!подскажите почему   при df = pd.json_normalize(res, 'data', 'arg') 'data' разбивается на колонки а arg нет?

Comment: Так реализован метод - данные пилит, а метаданные - нет. Как я это понимаю: метадата (данные о данных) - по сути некий ярлык, вносится целиком "как есть" и не предполагается к обработке.